# Update table using SELECT in WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

```
UPDATE table1 as t1
LEFT JOIN table2 as t2 ON t2.t1id = t1.id
LEFT JOIN table3 as t3 ON t3.t1id = t1.ID
SET t1.status = 4,
t2.status = 2,
t3.status = 2,
WHERE t2.status = 1
AND t3.StatusID = 1
AND t1.id IN (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( id
                 SEPARATOR "," ) AS IDs
                 FROM table1
                 WHERE table1.date < Date(NOW( ))
                 AND status IN ( 1, 2 )
                 ORDER BY GROUP_CONCAT( id ));
```

If I execute these query it give me error **"#1093 - You can't specify target table 'table1' for update in FROM clause**"

It's my Stored Procedure query
Please tell me what wrong in the query

Answer (score 0):

this should be your solution.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17032465/error-1093-you-cant-specify-target-table-relproductsprices-for-update-in-f

just use a nested table after

`t1.id IN(SELECT gc_id FROM ( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( id SEPARATOR "," ) AS IDs FROM table1    WHERE table1.date < Date(NOW( )) AND status IN ( 1, 2 ) ORDER BY GROUP_CONCAT( id )) AS TMP)`